# XML maximum limit?

Tags: php, xml, expressionengine

I'm using Expression Engine to generate a very large XML template. The generated XML is probably in the neighborhood of 1800 - 2000 lines. I've started to see a funky behavior where I add a new project my oldest project is no longer showing up in the XML. It is almost as if there is some kind of limit that it's reaching and pushing anything in after that limit forces the oldest item out. There are no errors on the page and the XML closes properly. Has anyone ever come across something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `channel:entries` tag (or `weblog:entries` on EE1) has a default limit of 1000 entries unless specified otherwise.  Try adding `limit="5000"` to your entries tag.

Comment: it actually defaults to 100 entries, but you were correct in that the limit parameter was the issue. We had 101 entries :D